# How to hide output of terminal command

Tags: go

I have a complex `ffmpeg` command to execute and I need to execute using Go. The command is working, the problem is coming when I try to hide the output of command using `> /dev/null 2>&1`

This is my code:

```
cmd := exec.Command(
    "ffmpeg",
    "-y",
    "-loglevel", "warning",
    "-i", ConvertImage,
    "-i", videoInput,
    "-c:v", cv,
    "-c:a", audioCodec,
    "-crf", fmt.Sprintf("%d", crf),
    "-map", "[v]",
    "-map", "1:a?",
    "-r", fmt.Sprintf("%d", Res.FrameRate),
    "-strict",
    "-2",
    outputFile,
    "> /dev/null 2>&1",
)
```

Without last field `"> /dev/null 2>&1",` code is working ok when I try to hide the output of command, command skip without the run.

What did I do wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: Also note that `ffmpeg` has a `-loglevel quiet` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put the output to a `bytes.Buffer` variable like following:

```
cmd := exec.Command(
    "ffmpeg",
    "-y",
    "-loglevel", "warning",
    "-i", ConvertImage,
    "-i", videoInput,
    "-c:v", cv,
    "-c:a", audioCodec,
    "-crf", fmt.Sprintf("%d", crf),
    "-map", "[v]",
    "-map", "1:a?",
    "-r", fmt.Sprintf("%d", Res.FrameRate),
    "-strict",
    "-2",
    outputFile,
)

var execOut bytes.Buffer
var execErr bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &execOut
cmd.Stderr = &execErr
```

By doing this, both the output and the error are in the corresponding buffer.

Now, if you want to print them, then you can use the following code snippet along with the above code:

```
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Cannot Execute cmd: ", err.Error())
}
outStr := execOut.String()
errStr := execErr.String()
if len(outStr) > 0 {
    fmt.Print(outStr)
}
if len(errStr) > 0 {
    fmt.Print(errStr)
}
```

**Update:** Or, if you do not need the stdout and stderr totally, then you can set the `cmd.Stdout` and `cmd.Stderr` to `nil` just like following:

```
cmd.Stdout = nil
cmd.Stderr = nil

err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Cannot Execute cmd: ", err.Error())
}
```

Comment: Also, as documented, [exec.Cmd.Stdout](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Stdout) can be set to `nil` to redirect to the null device. Some commands may write a *lot* of status to stdout and/or stderr and if you don't need it and are not going to look at it, you shouldn't buffer it.